# Inner Joins in redis

Tags: redis

I have a problem that is very similar to one mentioned here...

https://grokbase.com/t/gg/redis-db/123wv39cnt/filtering-zset-by-hash-field-value

But I am not able to understand the answer provided in that thread.

```
zadd scores 1.0 mary
zadd scores 2.0 sue
zadd scores 3.0 bob
zadd scores 4.0 bruce
zadd scores 5.0 maggie

sadd females mary sue maggie

zinterstore femscores 2 scores females

zrange femscores 0 50 withscores
```

How are the values 2, 3 and 6 calculated?

```
1) "mary"
2) "2"
3) "sue"
4) "3"
5) "maggie"
6) "6"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is the result of the default `WEIGHTS` and `AGGREGATE` as described in [`ZUNIONSTORE`](https://redis.io/commands/zunionstore).

Default `WEIGHTS` is 1, default `AGGREGATE` is `SUM`, so you are seeing the scores incremented by 1.

If you want the `scores` score without modification, simply set to zero the weight for `females`:

```
ZINTERSTORE femscores 2 scores females WEIGHTS 1 0
```